# Why can't I assign a UIView to self.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit

This might be a stupid question, but I'll shoot.

I made a little test project to test out a concept I had for a sliding view controller type of thing. I naively assumed I could create a UIView (let's call it peekView) with an outlet in a controller, and call something like [slidingControllerSlideFrom:self.view] from any visible view controller, the implementation of such being:

```
- (void)slidingControllerSlideFrom(UIView*)controllersMainView
{
    // push side controller to top of navigation stack

    self.peekView = controllersMainView;

    // sliding animation

}
```

But there is no effect. No crash, no warning, no change of view in the pushed controller.
Of course, the pushed controller crashes when trying to add self's view as a subview, but assigning it to a predefined UIView just results in nothing.

So, why? And if a mere 'why' is not enough of a question- what happens when I try to assign one controller's view another controller's subview, and what was the reason for designing UIKit where you cannot set views from `self.view`?

Comment: Where are you setting `self.view`? I don’t see that in your code anywhere…

Comment: Put a breakpoint just after your assignment and print out the value of the two views, including their superviews and frames.  It will likely make it easier to know what's going on.

Comment: @bdesham I reworded the example code to fit the question more precisely. Same effect though. `self.view` is defined by a xib and belongs to any arbitrary controller. `peekView` is a subview of the menu controller, which is also defined by a xib. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: I know there are many ways to implement a sliding controller, but that is not what my goal is here. I'm just trying to understand why and how setting a view from `self.view` is not allowed because it seems to be the most straightforward way to show view controllers' views in other controllers (Yes, there's addChildViewController but that's taboo in iPhone for some reason)

Comment: Just noticed your comment and updated my answer to try to answer what you actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have two options:

1 - If the controller in the peekView is always the same one in a given scene, use a "Container View". Those are explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6). Basically, they allow you to add a view in your scene that is managed by another controller.

2 - If the controller in the peekView depends on different conditions, you will have to create something similar to a custom tabbarcontroller. That means that you instantiate the controller that you need, add it's view as a subview of peekView (not assign the controller's view to the peekView itself) and then use `didmovetoparentviewcontroller` to notify the child controller. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5) might help.

**UPDATE:**

Just saw your comment, so let me answer what you actually asked: The `peekview` property is actually just a reference to the real UIView you placed in the screen. When you do this:

```
self.peekView = controllersMainView;
```

You are changing the reference, but no the view object itself. That's why you are not seeing any changes. There are ways of adding a new view to the controller from code, but it is much simpler to simply use `addSubview` to add your controllers view to a UIView that is already in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the discussion here: [subView Slide up from bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908143/subview-slide-up-from-bottom-of-the-screen)
and here: [SubView slide in animation, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343915/subview-slide-in-animation-iphone)

Hopefully that gives you a bit of framework on how to approach this task!